# Using unicorn and nginx for ruby 2.0.0 based rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, unicorn

I have been trying to configure unicorn and nginx to run my ruby 2.0.0 on rails 3.2.13 to run e-commerce application. I have been trying lot of the examples and blog and trying it out, but I am not to configure the unicorn and nginx. I am pasting nginx and unicorn files here. Kindly have a look into it. Initially I used to get 500 error now I am getting 400 bad request error.

**unicorn.rb**

```
root = "/home/ubuntu/apps/new_spree_st"
working_directory root
pid "#{root}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "#{root}/log/unicorn_stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{root}/log/unicorn_stdout.log"

listen "/tmp/unicorn.new_spree_st.sock"
worker_processes 4
timeout 30

# Force the bundler gemfile environment variable to
# reference the capistrano "current" symlink
before_exec do |_|
  ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = File.join(root, 'Gemfile')
end
```

**nginx.conf**

```
# This is example contains the bare mininum to get nginx going with Unicorn or Rainbows! servers.  Generally these configuration settings are 
# applicable to other HTTP application servers (and not just Ruby ones), so if you have one working well for proxying another app server, feel 
# free to continue using it.
#
# The only setting we feel strongly about is the fail_timeout=0
# directive in the "upstream" block.  max_fails=0 also has the same
# effect as fail_timeout=0 for current versions of nginx and may be
# used in its place.
#
# Users are strongly encouraged to refer to nginx documentation for more
# details and search for other example configs.

# you generally only need one nginx worker unless you're serving
# large amounts of static files which require blocking disk reads
#worker_connections 4096;
worker_processes 4;

# # drop privileges, root is needed on most systems for binding to port 80
# # (or anything < 1024).  Capability-based security may be available for
# # your system and worth checking out so you won't need to be root to
# # start nginx to bind on 80
#user nobody nogroup; # for systems with a "nogroup"
# user nobody nobody; # for systems with "nobody" as a group instead

# Feel free to change all paths to suite your needs here, of course
pid /etc/nginx/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.error.log;

events {
  worker_connections 4024; # increase if you have lots of clients
  accept_mutex off; # "on" if nginx worker_processes > 1
  # use epoll; # enable for Linux 2.6+
  # use kqueue; # enable for FreeBSD, OSX
}

http {
  # nginx will find this file in the config directory set at nginx build time
  include mime.types;

  # fallback in case we can't determine a type
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  # click tracking!
  access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.access.log combined;

  # you generally want to serve static files with nginx since neither
  # Unicorn nor Rainbows! is optimized for it at the moment
  sendfile on;

  tcp_nopush on; # off may be better for *some* Comet/long-poll stuff
  tcp_nodelay off; # on may be better for some Comet/long-poll stuff

  # we haven't checked to see if Rack::Deflate on the app server is
  # faster or not than doing compression via nginx.  It's easier
  # to configure it all in one place here for static files and also
  # to disable gzip for clients who don't get gzip/deflate right.
  # There are other gzip settings that may be needed used to deal with
  # bad clients out there, see http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpGzipModule
  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_min_length 500;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_types text/plain text/html text/xml text/css
             text/comma-separated-values
             text/javascript application/x-javascript
             application/atom+xml;

  # this can be any application server, not just Unicorn/Rainbows!
  upstream app_server {
    # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
    # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
    # single worker for timing out).

    # for UNIX domain socket setups:
    server 127.0.0.1:80 fail_timeout=0;

    # for TCP setups, point these to your backend servers
    # server 192.168.0.7:8080 fail_timeout=0;
    # server 192.168.0.8:8080 fail_timeout=0;
    # server 192.168.0.9:8080 fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {
    # enable one of the following if you're on Linux or FreeBSD
    # listen 80 default deferred; # for Linux
    # listen 80 default accept_filter=httpready; # for FreeBSD

    # If you have IPv6, you'll likely want to have two separate listeners.
    # One on IPv4 only (the default), and another on IPv6 only instead
    # of a single dual-stack listener.  A dual-stack listener will make
    # for ugly IPv4 addresses in $remote_addr (e.g ":ffff:10.0.0.1"
    # instead of just "10.0.0.1") and potentially trigger bugs in
    # some software.
    # listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on; # deferred or accept_filter recommended

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    # ~2 seconds is often enough for most folks to parse HTML/CSS and
    # retrieve needed images/icons/frames, connections are cheap in
    # nginx so increasing this is generally safe...
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # path for static files
     root /home/ubuntu/apps/new_spree_st/public;

    # Prefer to serve static files directly from nginx to avoid unnecessary
    # data copies from the application server.
    #
    # try_files directive appeared in in nginx 0.7.27 and has stabilized
    # over time.  Older versions of nginx (e.g. 0.6.x) requires
    # "if (!-f $request_filename)" which was less efficient:
    # http://bogomips.org/unicorn.git/tree/examples/nginx.conf?id=v3.3.1#n127
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
      # an HTTP header important enough to have its own Wikipedia entry:
      #   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      # enable this if you forward HTTPS traffic to unicorn,
      # this helps Rack set the proper URL scheme for doing redirects:
      # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # pass the Host: header from the client right along so redirects
      # can be set properly within the Rack application
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

      # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
      # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
      proxy_redirect off;

      # set "proxy_buffering off" *only* for Rainbows! when doing
      # Comet/long-poll/streaming.  It's also safe to set if you're using
      # only serving fast clients with Unicorn + nginx, but not slow
      # clients.  You normally want nginx to buffer responses to slow
      # clients, even with Rails 3.1 streaming because otherwise a slow
      # client can become a bottleneck of Unicorn.
      #
      # The Rack application may also set "X-Accel-Buffering (yes|no)"
      # in the response headers do disable/enable buffering on a
      # per-response basis.
      # proxy_buffering off;

      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

    # Rails error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
      root /home/ubuntu/apps/new_spree_st/public;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your unicorn process is listening on a socket, however your `app_server` directive for Nginx is directing traffic to TCP port 80 (which assuming Nginx is running on port 80, is just redirecting traffic back to itself in an endless loop).

See the [sample unicorn nginx config file](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/examples/nginx.conf). Similar to that, your `app_server` should look like this:

```
upstream app_server {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.new_spree_st.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
```